# How to count all child nodes of a Asp Treeview levelwise(depthwise)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, treeview

I have created a treeview from database.I can get all data of selected node but now i want to count all child nodes od treeview depthwise.Thanks in advance.

Comment: level order traversal should do it.

Comment: What have you tried? Research some algorithms as Shyju suggested. This is not a new or unique problem, you should be able to find plenty of existing theory and maybe even code samples. If you try it and get stuck then please post your code here and people can try and fix it.